# scp to host, without a specifc path using subdomain

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, scp

I'm wondering if there was some way to scp a file, without specifying a path, so instead of

```
scp example example@example.com:/path/to/directory
```

then do this

```
scp example example@sub.example.com
```

and then the host already knows which directory you want to scp the file to, because of the subdomain.

is it something that can be configured?

Im using a Ubuntu 16.0.4 server running a Nginx webserver.
I want it to do simplified transfer between test env, to the production folder on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Unlike HTTP, ssh has no knowledge of which host and the client used to connect.

Comment: could you instead make  script that, when a specific user logs on, automaticly cd's to a specific folder? so the folder is based on the user, and not subdomain?

Comment: I suppose, yes. Seems much ado about nothing, though, when the path can be simply provided on the CLI.

Comment: it's because I am opening my server to host other people's websites, so I don't want them to navigate through my entire system, if it can be prevented.

Comment: So set their home directory to wherever you want them to land when connecting.